# Need dynamic interactive line graph for r-markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have created a graph using ggplot2 in R. Each line of multiple lines is a separate file so that I could color it independently.

```
ggplot() +
   geom_line(data = dat22, aes(x=YEAR, y=RO_MM, group = HUC8, color= HUC8))+
   geom_line(data = dat21, aes(x=YEAR, y=RO_MM, group = HUC8, color= HUC8))+
   geom_line(data = dat20, aes(x=YEAR, y=RO_MM, group = HUC8, color= HUC8))+ 
   geom_line(data = dat19, aes(x=YEAR, y=RO_MM, group = HUC8, color= HUC8))+
   geom_line(data = dat18, aes(x=YEAR, y=RO_MM, group = HUC8, color= HUC8))+
   scale_color_manual(values = c("gray","gray","gray","gray","gray"))
```

I thought this would make it simple to include a line for each one for an *alternate* color, so that I could make the graph interactive. The goal is that a viewer would click on a line in the legend and that line would turn red and s/he would be able to compare it to the reference line in black. But meanwhile all the other lines would be unobtrusively gray. And this could be done for each line individually.

[image]

I am finding very little at all to do with interactive line graphs and have found nothing that shows me how to do this. The closest I've come is `streamgraph` and that creates a stacked graph which I do not want. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You may want to use `plotly` package, it may require a little bit of knowledge to have 1 line stay black, but plotly should work for line graphs

Comment: I have looked into `plotly`. If I could have two sets of info combined into one graph, ie: the data above as *line1* and a second line with just the black-line data as *line2* then it would work. I haven't been able to figure out how to use `plotly` to create the `onclick` at all.